# Puzzled about function implementation of module design

Tags: javascript

Reading http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html made me to ask myself how is the module declaration in the article:

```
(function () {
    // ... 
}());
```

different to what I would do in this case:

```
(function () {
    // ... 
})();
```

Both are executed immediately, have access to globals...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're equivalent. JSLint on default settings would make you prefer the former.